# Angular On click stop propagation event

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, stoppropagation

How Do I make a call to Angular function in my jQuery code? I tried the f

```html
$(document).on('click', '.myBtn', function(e) {
    angular.element($(".someClass")).scope().clearBtnItems();
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log("stop..prop");
});
```

But i get following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: angular.element(...).scope(...).clearAllResortsOption is not a function
```

So, how do I know which ID is bound to my controller? I am new to AJS and this is an existing AJS app which I am modifying. So I am not sure, dynamically how the controllers are injected?

Comment: if you wanna do it in angular do in this way  :  $event.stopPropagation(); Also you are trying click function , Instead you can use ng-click ="someFunction" in your controller write your jQuery stuff in this  someFunction()

Comment: I tried those things but before even function gets called event propogates and hence i am trying to call AJS fn. in jQuery. In html template they have referred it as sm.clearBtnItems, so I need to find what this sm is

Comment: are you getting event bubbling issue....

Comment: yes. I am trying to avoid even bubbling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
write seperate ng-click for both parent and child
```

```
<div ng-click = "sm.clearBtnItems()"><div ng-click ="removeBubbling($event)"></div>
```

```
 $scope.removeBubbling = function($event){
      // do some code here
      // Prevent bubbling to showItem.
      // On recent browsers, only $event.stopPropagation() is needed
      if ($event.stopPropagation) $event.stopPropagation();
      if ($event.preventDefault) $event.preventDefault();
            $event.cancelBubble = true;
            $event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it in angular way:

Use `ng-click` in your template instead of using jQuery `click` event.

The second thing: you do not need to wrap jQuery inside angular DOM selector, because `angular.element` is doing exactly the same as jQuery `$(".someClass")`.

And what does `scope()` in your example?

Comment: I tried ng-click but, even before calling that function the event propogates and closes the dropdown menu

Comment: Hence, I was trying to call my controller function using scope

Comment: @Smitha additionally do pass $event object to controller method from `ng-click` like `ng-click="someFunction($event)"` & then play with $event in your function..

Comment: But my "someFunction($event)" is not getting called. Before that it bubbles

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `e.stopPropagation();` It's in the angular selector.

`angular.element($(".someClass")) // << This is wrong`

It should be

`angular.element(".someClass")`

Comment: I tried this : angular.element(".searchBarBG").scope().clearAllResortsOption();. Still same error